# getting values out of XML using LINQ to XML

Tags: linq-to-xml

I hate to be the village idiot, but I have no clue how Linq to XML works.  I know it is supposed to be like writing a SQL query, but I just can't wrap my head around it.  I am trying to get data out of an XML string.  I don't want to use XMLDocuments and XPath to do this.  I could do that, I did do that, I am trying to make my application a bit more snazzy.  The XML that I have is a little bit onerous, but I was able to use Xpath to parse it.  Linq to XML is supposed to be so much easier.  From the following XML I need to get all the elements out of there and bind them to a POCO object.  For instance I need to set a Patient.PatientId object with the value attribute (4563) of the element node with the PatientID name attribute.  Now, I could understand how to do this using an XmlDocument.  But I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this with LINQ to XML?  What can I do?  I have an example of what I am attempting to do below the xml that is giving me trouble.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dataTemplateSpecification id="id1" name="name1" >
  <templates xmlns="">
    <template>
      <elements>
        <element id="element0" name="PatientId" display="Patient ID" dataType="String" visable="true" readOnly="false" value="4563">
          <mapping path="//Template/TemplateData/ACOData/PATIENT_ID" />
          <validation>
            <rules>
              <rule id="r0" test="#element0.value == ''">
                <fail>
                  <html>
                    <b>Patient ID is null, value must be present</b>
                  </html>
                </fail>
              </rule>
            </rules>
          </validation>
        </element>
        <element id="element1" name="PopulationPatientID" display="Population Patient ID" dataType="String" visable="true" readOnly="true" enc="2098" value="6407">
          <mapping path="//Template/TemplateData/ACOData/POPULATION_PATIENT_ID" />
          <!--Patient/compositeID[./idType='populationPatientID']/id-->
          <validation>
            <rules>
              <rule id="r1" test="#element1.value == ''">
                <fail>
                  <html>
                    <b>EMPI ID is null, value must be present</b>
                  </html>
                </fail>
              </rule>
            </rules>
          </validation>
        </element>
```

Again, Here is the LINQ to XML that I am trying to use.

```
TemplateModel template = (TemplateModel)(from templates in elem.XPathSelectElements("//templates/template")
select new PatientACOData
{ 
       PatientId = templates.Elements("//element/element[@name='PatientId']").Attributes("value").Value;

});
```

UPDATE>>> THE ABOVE EXAMPLE CLASS DEFINITION WAS SLIGHTLY TO) SIMPLE... Here is the appropriate class definition...

```
class PatientClass
{
    public int Item_ID { get; set; }
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public int EMPIID { get; set; }
    //public int PopulationPatientID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string HostpitalFinNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime AdminDate { get; set; }
    public string MRNType { get; set; }
    public string MRN { get; set; }
    public string PatientRoomPhone { get; set; }
    public DateTime DischargeDateTime { get; set; }
    public string DischargeDisposition { get; set; }
    public string DischargeTo { get; set; }
    public char DischargeAdvocateCall { get; set; }
    public string Payor { get; set; }
    public char HomeHealthCareAccepted { get; set; }
    public char SafeLandingAccepted { get; set; }
    public string PCPName { get; set; }
    public string PCPPhone { get; set; }
    public string SpecialistName { get; set; }
    public string SpecialistPhone { get; set; }
    public DateTime PCPAppointmentDateTime { get; set; }
    public string PCPAppointmentLocation { get; set; }
    public DateTime SpecialistAppointmentDateTime { get; set; }
    public string SpecialistAppointmentLocation { get; set; }
    public char CompletedPathway { get; set; }
    public string CompletedPathwayReason { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is this still actual for you? Which output are you expecting?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  I am attempting to pull the data from that XML into a data object.  I am trying a couple of different ways, but the hurdle for me is learning linq to XML

Comment: Please share a "data object" class definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your XML i would fill PatientClass as follows:

```
var xml = XElement.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

var patients = from template in xml.Element("templates").Elements("template")
                select new PatientClass
                {
                    PatientId = (from element in template.Element("elements").Elements("element")
                                where element.Attribute("name").Value == "PatientId"
                                select (int)element.Attribute("value")).FirstOrDefault()

                };
```