# Why is my Linq to Xml query failing?

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml, poco

I have been trying off and on to populate an object from an XML string.  I am a complete nincompoop at Linq, so I decide to kind of combine Linq and XPath... Here is the sad attempt...

```
public static PatientClass getDataFromXMLintoPOCO(string xml)
{
        PatientClass patClass = null;


        string xmlFromSvc = xml;
        XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlFromSvc);
        XElement elem = xDocument.Element("dataTemplateSpecification");

        PatientClass template = (PatientClass)(from templates in elem.XPathSelectElements(string.Format("//templates/template[./elements/element[@name=\"PopulationPatientID\"and @value='{0}' and @enc='{1}']]", "1", 0))
                                               select new PatientClass
                                                     {
                                                         PatientId = int.Parse(templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='PatientId']").Attribute("value").Value),
                                                         EMPIID = int.Parse(templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='EMPIID']").Attribute("value").Value),
                                                         //public int PopulationPatientID { get; set; }
                                                         FirstName = templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='FirstName']").Attribute("value").Value,
                                                         LastName = templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='LastName']").Attribute("value").Value,
                                                         DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse(templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='DateOfBirth']").Attribute("value").Value),
                                                         Phone = templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='Phone']").Attribute("value").Value,
                                                         HostpitalFinNumber = templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='HostpitalFinNumber']").Attribute("value").Value,
                                                         AdminDate = DateTime.Parse(templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='AdminDate']").Attribute("value").Value),
                                                         MRNType = templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='MRNType']").Attribute("value").Value,
                                                         MRN = templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='MRN']").Attribute("value").Value,
                                                         PatientRoomPhone = templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='PatientRoomPhone']").Attribute("value").Value,
                                                         DischargeDateTime = DateTime.Parse(templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='DischargeDateTime']").Attribute("value").Value),
                                                         DischargeDisposition = templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='DischargeDisposition']").Attribute("value").Value,
                                                         DischargeTo = templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='DischargeTo']").Attribute("value").Value,
                                                         DischargeAdvocateCall = templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='DischargeAdvocateCall']").Attribute("value").Value.ToCharArray()[0],
                                                         Payor = templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='Payor']").Attribute("value").Value,
                                                         HomeHealthCareAccepted = templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='HomeHealthCareAccepted']").Attribute("value").Value.ToCharArray()[0],
                                                         SafeLandingAccepted = templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='SafeLandingAccepted']").Attribute("value").Value.ToCharArray()[0],
                                                         PCPName = templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='PCPName']").Attribute("value").Value,
                                                         PCPPhone = templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='PCPPhone']").Attribute("value").Value,
                                                         SpecialistName = templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='SpecialistName']").Attribute("value").Value,
                                                         SpecialistPhone = templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='SpecialistPhone']").Attribute("value").Value,
                                                         PCPAppointmentDateTime = DateTime.Parse(templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='PCPAppointmentDateTime']").Attribute("value").Value),
                                                         PCPAppointmentLocation = templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='PCPAppointmentLocation']").Attribute("value").Value,
                                                         SpecialistAppointmentDateTime = DateTime.Parse(templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='SpecialistAppointmentDateTime']").Attribute("value").Value),
                                                         SpecialistAppointmentLocation = templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='SpecialistAppointmentLocation']").Attribute("value").Value,
                                                         CompletedPathway = templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='CompletedPathway']").Attribute("value").Value.ToCharArray()[0],
                                                         CompletedPathwayReason = templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='CompletedPathwayReason']").Attribute("value").Value,
                                                         Comment = templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='Comment']").Attribute("value").Value
                                                     }).AsEnumerable();
        //return template != null ? template : null;

        return patClass != null ? patClass : null;
    }
}
```

The object that I am trying to fill is like so...

```
class PatientClass
{
    public int Item_ID { get; set; }
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public int EMPIID { get; set; }
    //public int PopulationPatientID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string HostpitalFinNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime AdminDate { get; set; }
    public string MRNType { get; set; }
    public string MRN { get; set; }
    public string PatientRoomPhone { get; set; }
    public DateTime DischargeDateTime { get; set; }
    public string DischargeDisposition { get; set; }
    public string DischargeTo { get; set; }
    public char DischargeAdvocateCall { get; set; }
    public string Payor { get; set; }
    public char HomeHealthCareAccepted { get; set; }
    public char SafeLandingAccepted { get; set; }
    public string PCPName { get; set; }
    public string PCPPhone { get; set; }
    public string SpecialistName { get; set; }
    public string SpecialistPhone { get; set; }
    public DateTime PCPAppointmentDateTime { get; set; }
    public string PCPAppointmentLocation { get; set; }
    public DateTime SpecialistAppointmentDateTime { get; set; }
    public string SpecialistAppointmentLocation { get; set; }
    public char CompletedPathway { get; set; }
    public string CompletedPathwayReason { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

The XML is to massive and weildy.  It strikes fear into the common man, that I can assure you.  I cut out most of it just so it can appear readable...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dataTemplateSpecification id="id1" name="name1" >
    <templates xmlns="">
        <template>
            <elements>
                <element id="element0" name="PatientId" display="Patient ID" dataType="String" visable="true" readOnly="false" value="4563">
                    <mapping path="//Template/TemplateData/ACOData/PATIENT_ID" />
                    <validation>
                        <rules>
                            <rule id="r0" test="#element0.value == ''">
                                <fail>
                                    <html>
                                        <b>Patient ID is null, value must be present</b>
                                    </html>
                                </fail>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </validation>
                </element>
                <element id="element1" name="PopulationPatientID" display="Population Patient ID" dataType="String" visable="true" readOnly="true" enc="2098" value="6407">
                    <mapping path="//Template/TemplateData/ACOData/POPULATION_PATIENT_ID" />
                    <!--Patient/compositeID[./idType='populationPatientID']/id-->
                    <validation>
                        <rules>
                            <rule id="r1" test="#element1.value == ''">
                                <fail>
                                    <html>
                                        <b>EMPI ID is null, value must be present</b>
                                    </html>
                                </fail>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </validation>
                </element>
                <element id="element2" name="EMPIID" display="EMPIID" dataType="String" visable="true" readOnly="true" value="">
                    <mapping path="//Template/TemplateData/ACOData/EMPI" />
                    <!--//Templates/Patient/sources/source/empi"/>-->
                    <validation>
                        <rules>
                            <rule id="r1" test="#element1.value == ''">
                                <fail>
                                    <html>
                                        <b>EMPI ID is null, value must be present</b>
                                    </html>
                                </fail>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </validation>
                </element>
                <element id="element2" name="PRELOADMPACMRN" display="MPACMRN" dataType="String" visable="true" readOnly="true" value="">
                    <mapping path="//Template/Patient/sources/source/mpacmrn" />
                    <validation>
                        <rules>
                            <rule id="r1" test="#element1.value == ''">
                                <fail>
                                    <html>
                                        <b>EMPI ID is null, value must be present</b>
                                    </html>
                                </fail>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </validation>
                </element>
            </elements>
            <dataTypeSpecifications>
                <dataTypeSpecification id="" baseType="KeyValuePair">
                    <dictionaryDefinition>
                        <item key="0" value="-SELECT-" />
                        <item key="1" value="YES" />
                        <item key="2" value="NO" />
                    </dictionaryDefinition>
                </dataTypeSpecification>
            </dataTypeSpecifications>
        </template>
    </templates>
</dataTemplateSpecification>
```

Apparently, I am getting a casting error of sorts.  First question, there has got to be an easier cleaner way to do this than what I am doing right now.  Any suggestions for cleaning this up.  Also, Why am I getting a casting error?  Any help given will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: List the casting error...  I see `PatientClass template = (PatientClass) (from ...).AsEnumerable();` . Start by losing the `.AsEnumerable()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting values out of XML using LINQ to XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641746/getting-values-out-of-xml-using-linq-to-xml)

Comment: And please don't repost. You can edit your questions.

Comment: Ugh! This XML design has all the hallmarks of someone trying to reinvent the wheel and poorly understanding proper system design boundaries. Not intermixing validation and UI design with data would be a great idea. Also, have they never heard of XSD schemas where you're working?

Comment: They have (heard of XSD's), and so have I.  Frankly, I am not sure why the design came down the way it did.  And sorry for reposting.  I thought this was different enough to warrant a new thread (with all the new details and so forth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the complexity of your input XML document, I would expect that you will need a pretty complex piece of C# code to parse it and transform into the class you have given!

One thing I would point out is that your XPaths such as "elements/element[@name='PatientId']" can be converted into an equivalent Linq query as follows:

```
templates.Descendents("element").Single(el => el.Attribute("name")=="PatientId")
```

This doesn't really make you code much simpler, but it does at least mean you are not mixing Linq and XPath.

Answer (score 1):

The XML you pasted was malformed, but after correcting it, this worked:

```
    string expression = string.Format("//templates/template[./elements/element[@name=\"PopulationPatientID\"and @value='{0}' and @enc='{1}']]", "6407", "2098");

    IEnumerable<XElement> elements = elem.XPathSelectElements(expression);

    IEnumerable<PatientClass> matchingPatients =
        from templates in elements select new PatientClass
                    {
                        PatientId =
                            int.Parse(
                                templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='PatientId']").Attribute(
                                    "value").Value),
                         [... whatever you had before.. ]
```